# Sharepoint Logshipping

Tags: sharepoint-server

After log shipping the content databases from SharePoint 2013 to a second farm and having everything working fine . My question is how can users log on to the SharePoint on the second farm using the same credentials from the primary farm ( Keep in mine the two SharePoint farm are not on the same domain). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How the second farm is configured? Users on the domain will be able to access the Site if they are imported using the User Profile Service Application.

Comment: The second farm was configured with its own AD and its also using the content database of the first farm that is all

Comment: is their any trust between both domains? did you test if user from either domain user can access the sharepoint?

Comment: Well their is no trust relationship between the two domains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a general problem with SharePoint. Even if you restore the site collections from one data center to another operating in different domain then you would get an access denied error.

The best approach for this will be using an STSADM or powershell script to add the users based on target domain including sitecollection administrators.